# Manipulate does not work if an equation with a variable parameter is not explicitly written

Tags: graphics, manipulate, programming

I have a little problem using the Manipulate command.

I am trying to write down the parameter control of a function that is entered into this command not explicitly. But in this case, the variable parameter "does not cling" to the function and the command does not work.

I will show what I mean.

In this case, the command works successfully.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[2*(x + x^Sin[1*a])], {x, 0, 30}], {a, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

In this case, nothing happens.

```
f = Sin[2*(x + x^Sin[1*a])]

Manipulate[Plot[f, {x, 0, 30}], {a, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

At the same time, RegionPlot3D, SurfacePlot3D, etc. successfully work as I need.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems I found a solution: [Append multiple plots with Manipulate](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1313104)

I mean, we need "constructions" like this. I'm right? That is, write the parameters to the function name in square brackets.
`Fx [b_, c_, y_, x_]: = Sin [x / c] + Cos [b y]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_, a_] := Sin[2*(x + x^Sin[1*a])]

Manipulate[Plot[f[x, a], {x, 0, 30}], {a, 0, 10}]
```

Have fun!

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you!